# angular select box reset with unique filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have been looking at all the already answered questions and i cannot seem to get it to work with the unique filter already on there. i want to be able to reset the filter back to 0

```html
<select class="form-control" ng-model="search.jobTitle">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="jTitle in jobTitleList | unique:'jobTitle'">{{jTitle.jobTitle }}</option>
</select>
```

it is setup to display the job titles that are in the array, i have the unique filter so there will not be duplicates of the same title. it has kept me from using the examples already on here.  thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sscce? http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: instead of `unique` filter you [can use `track by jTitle.jobTitle`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: this is what i am getting in the console.  Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: jTitle in jobTitleList track by jTitle.jobTitle, Duplicate key: Software Developer